# Using dynamic Pinia stores when Vue route changes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I have an app that has a handful of dynamic components and each one needs it's own store. I'm having anm issue referencing the correct Pinia store when each route changes. The store id is based off the current route. See code below.

This is the component that creates / uses the store.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import makeStore from "./store";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();
const id = route.params.widgetID;

const store = makeStore(id);

// now i use the store in my template
</script>
```

This code creates a new store with the given id:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default function makeStore(id: string) {
  return defineStore(id, () => {
    const testString = ref("");
    return { testString };
  })();
}
```

The issue is when I have the route update, the store doesn't because it's originally created with the first components params. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using a ID depending on the route and just not the component/widget name to initialize the store? Why do the components need a store in general?Is their state changed from alot of other places in your app?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat its a lot of different types of dynamic components and each needs to manage their own state. The user can create / remove various components at runtime.

Comment: What prevents you from storing the component state in the component itself if each of the single components needs to have its own state?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat honestly my app is a larger thing than the example here. I need to figure out an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `onBeforeRouteUpdate` to initialize correct store

```
let store = makeStore(route.meta.widgetId ?? 'default');
onBeforeRouteUpdate((to) => {
  store = makeStore(to.meta.widgetId);
});
```

I assume that your component code is base route component. When you navigate to child routes - Vue does not re-render base component if no dependency was updated. Same goes if 2 separate routes will use same component.

I did setup [complete playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qqqwxe?file=src%2Froutes%2Fbase.vue). You can put some text in input, then switch between routes to verify that input value persists based on `widgetId`

Comment: Thanks for this. I was headed in the same direction as well. Do you think the store variable needs to be a ref? or a shallow ref?

Comment: That depends on your use case, which is not really described in this question. If there is specific case under question - it shall be filed as other question